# Why is object deviating from path random?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have an object that is following a path ... and at some point (checkout the blend file) it is offseting from path, why?

How can I fix this.

http://flester.ro/path-deviation-2.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have 2 curves overlaying, curba1 and curba2, so it's a little bit confusing. About the useful one, curba2: it's very long, so you need to increase its resolution if you want the movement of the sphere to be smooth (in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape* > *Resolution* > *Preview* and *Render*). Also, you've given an animation to your sphere (which makes it move away from the curve) but I guess it's on purpose.

[image]

Comment: the other path is same path but for different object, so you can ignore it. Looks like  Preview u Resolution is the problem. thank you!